# Laravel Cashier cancel() throws a BadMethodCallException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-cashier

I used Laravel Cashier to handle my user's subscription, however when I try to do the basic cancellation `$user->subscription('main')->cancel()`, an exception is being thrown

> BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::asStripeCustomer() in
>
> \try\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php:2483

Stack trace:

> `\try\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1470): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->__call('asStripeCustome...', Array)`
>
> `\try\vendor\laravel\cashier\src\Subscription.php(345): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('asStripeCustome...', Array)`
>
> `\try\vendor\laravel\cashier\src\Subscription.php(256): Laravel\Cashier\Subscription->asStripeSubscription()`

I setup the Model correctly and I uses the `Billable` trait so I really have no idea what's really causing this error

App\User.php

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

class User extends Authenticatable{
   use Billable;

   ...
}
```

App\Http\Controllers\UserController.php

```
public function cancelSubscription(Request $request)
{
    $user = $request->user();

    try {
        if ($user->subscription('main')->onTrial()) {
            $user->subscription('main')->cancelNow();
        } else {
            $user->subscription('main')->cancel();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Log::error($e);
        return [
            'success' => 0,
            'message' => "Something went wrong while trying cancel your subscription. Please try again later."
        ];
    }
```

Any help and hints will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, I just found out that it was actually with my stripe configuration on `/config/services.php` as I have two models for my Users (because I'm also using another package other than `laravel-cashier` to handle payments via Authorize.net on which I ended up creating different Models for them to work)

```
'stripe' => [
    // 'model' => App\AnetUser::class, => this actually caused the error as
               // ->asStripeCustomer() doesn't exists on an Authorize.net's Billable trait 
    'model' => App\User::class,
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
],
```

I feel so stupid. XD

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've never worked with Laravel Cashier before but, I think the root of your problem might be that you are accessing user from the request, therefore it's not a user instance thats why it triggers undefined methods errors.

So creating a user instance should probably work out for you:

*Note: I don't know if $request->user is primary key or whole user instance so I added different solutions*

```
public function cancelSubscription(Request $request)
{
    // if $request->user is the user instance you can do this:
    $user = App\User::findOrFail($request->user->id);

    // if $request->user was any other field from user you could retrieve
    // the user using something like-> 
   // App\User::where('fieldName', 'LIKE', $request->user)->firstOrFail();


    try {
        if ($user->subscription('main')->onTrial()) {
            $user->subscription('main')->cancelNow();
        } else {
            $user->subscription('main')->cancel();
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        \Log::error($e);
        return [
            'success' => 0,
            'message' => "Something went wrong while trying cancel your subscription. Please try again later."
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip but I already tried that, finding the user directly from the model `$user = App\User::find($request->user()->id)` then `$user->subscription('main')->cancel()` still same error is thrown. Really weird, as it always work on my other projects, just this time. T_T

Comment: can you dd($user) maybe `App\User::find($request->user()->id)` isn't working; so you can pass an instance with the request? I thought user()->id shouldn't return you anything, how are you passing the $user?

Comment: thanks for your time in helping me, anyway I have found where I went wrong, it was actually on my stripe configuration on `/config/services.php`, I feel so stupid lol XD

Comment: if you look on Illuminate\Http\Request, there's a `user()` function there which will return the current user sending the request. That's why I use `$request->user()->id` :)